# How can I set sub directory in nginx-bitnami-CI?

Tags: php, codeigniter, nginx, bitnami

I'm using Nginx bitnami codeigniter server.

With the existing codeigniter project in place in the root folder, it is now necessary to add a new application to the subfolder.
In apache, just make a subfolder and copy the codeigniter into it, but in nginx it continues to connect as an application of root, treating subfolder as a controller, and 404 error occurs.
How should I set it up?

this is my Bitnami config file.

```
server { 
    listen       80; 
    server_name  localhost; 
    include "/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/bitnami/phpfastcgi.conf"; 
    include "/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf"; 
     ## Root and index files. 
    root /opt/bitnami/nginx/html; 
    index  index.php index.html index.htm; 
    ## If no favicon exists return a 204 (no content error). 
    location = /favicon.ico { 
        try_files $uri =204; 
        log_not_found off; 
        access_log off; 
    } 
    ## Don't log robots.txt requests. 
    location = /robots.txt { 
        allow all; 
        log_not_found off; 
        access_log off; 
    } 
    ## Try the requested URI as files before handling it to PHP. 
    location / { 
        proxy_buffers 8 1024k; 
        proxy_buffer_size 1024k; 
        ## Regular PHP processing. 
        location ~ \.php$ { 
            try_files  $uri =404; 
            #fastcgi_pass   php_processes; 
            fastcgi_pass unix:/opt/bitnami/php/var/run/www.sock; 
            fastcgi_index  index.php; 
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name; 
            include        fastcgi_params; 
        } 
        ## Static files 
        location ~* \.(?:css|gif|htc|ico|js|jpe?g|png|swf)$ { 
            expires max; 
            log_not_found off; 
            ## No need to bleed constant updates. Send the all shebang in one 
            ## fell swoop. 
            tcp_nodelay off; 
            ## Set the OS file cache. 
            open_file_cache max=1000 inactive=120s; 
            open_file_cache_valid 45s; 
            open_file_cache_min_uses 2; 
            open_file_cache_errors off; 
        } 
        ## Keep a tab on the 'big' static files. 
        location ~* ^.+\.(?:ogg|pdf|pptx?)$ { 
            expires 30d; 
            ## No need to bleed constant updates. Send the all shebang in one 
            ## fell swoop. 
            tcp_nodelay off; 
        } 
    } # / location 
    if (!-e $request_filename ) { 
          rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php last; 
    } 
}
```

and this code is redirect all path to indx.php.

```
if (!-e $request_filename ) { 
          rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php last; 
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you deploy your application inside the `/opt/bitnami/nginx/html` directory (root directory of NGINX)? If you used a different path, you will need to configure NGINX to serve those files

You can deploy a custom PHP application from scratch, following the steps below. These steps assume that your application will live in the /opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/ directory:

- Run the following commands to create the directories and assign the necessary permissions:

```
sudo mkdir /opt/bitnami/apps/myapp
sudo mkdir /opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/htdocs/
sudo mkdir /opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/conf
sudo chown -R bitnami:daemon /opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/htdocs/
sudo chmod -R g+w /opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/htdocs/
```

- Create and edit the /opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/conf/nginx-prefix.conf file and add the line below to it:

```
location /myapp {
  alias "/opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/htdocs/";
  include "/opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/conf/nginx-app.conf";
}
```

- Create and edit the /opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/conf/nginx-app.conf file and add the content below to it. This is the main configuration file for your application, so modify it further depending on your application’s requirements.

```
index index.php index.html index.htm;
location ~ \.php$ {
  fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
  fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
  fastcgi_pass unix:/opt/bitnami/php/var/run/www.sock;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
  include fastcgi_params;
}
```

- Add the following line to the end of the /opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf file:

```
include "/opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/conf/nginx-prefix.conf";
```

- Restart the NGINX server:

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart nginx
```

- Access the application at http://SERVER-IP/myapp.

You can find more information in our documentation: https://docs.bitnami.com/general/infrastructure/nginx/administration/create-custom-application-php/